# PhoneGap & CMS integration

Tags: php, javascript, cordova, content-management-system, expressionengine

I'm trying to traverse the whole PhoneGap thing to get a native app up and running. I am completely fine with creating html5 markup for the actual app, what I need help with is trying to pull in dynamic content from a website. In particular, there is some content on our website that also needs to be in the app. We use a program call Expression Engine that handles all of our content. The content that I would need to pull over would be:

- Sermon Videos
- Sermon Series
- Locations
- Plain text content

The majority of the app will be local, but there are some dynamic needs as you can see. I've read a couple things that say "JSON" is the way to go, but it looks pretty complicated as I'm not quite familiar with AJAX. Is this the only way or are there any options or resources anyone can point me to that might help. I'm not even sure if that method would work for our website. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you're pulling in external content then your app will likely be declined by the app markets. Apple especially have a strict policy when it comes to content changing outside the app scope.

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with loading *content* into an app at runtime. The issue is with pulling *code* (such as JavaScript) in that might change the basic functionality of the app after it has been approved.

Comment: So going the JSON/AJAX route I can't really pull any script in, correct? I'm assuming that would be an acceptable format for the apple machine.

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13443874/763010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct. What you need to look into is AJAX/JSON and how to present your data to your app using these technologies.

Expression Engine would actually be quite a good choice for this as its template system is quite flexible. There are even add-on modules for delivering your content as JSON if you want t go that route.

A quick google led me to: http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/

It's a bit more than you need since you will have your content in an existing CMS instead of creating a new database to store the data, but the concepts will hold true and I am sure you will be able to use it to find more tutorials that suit you better.

Comment: So then the first step would be to transform my website into JSON friendly content through a plug in? And then follow that tutorial on how to pull in the JSON content and reformat it? I appreciate your help!