# Setting up a CMS for a Phonegap / Cordova iphone app

Tags: ios, cordova, content-management-system, phonegap-plugins

When making a iphone app with Phonegap / Cordova is it possible to attach a web based CMS to it, to pull the data down from, so that a non technical user could update the app ?

Usualy you'd just build them using html, css, jquery/js but i wandered if there was an easier way to update them ?

Comment: So you mean a cms as the main content or only a script to update the app ?

Comment: Yeah, to add pages and content only. No design, setting ect like all the options you get on a full blown CMS like wordpress / drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a normal cms on a server like a webpage so normal joomla wordpress etc.

Then you add the url to the phonegap whitelist and load it like the normal phonegap html url.

Comment: ah, ok so have the site blocked to search engines with the robots.txt and the site itself a mobile site

Comment: also if its just a splash screen and then loads a website will apple approve that to the app store ?

Comment: i think that would work , but i don't know about the approving process

Comment: Definitely wouldn't get approved, unless you happen to get a reviewer who isn't paying attention.

Comment: but isn't the wikipedia app just that ? it's based on phonegap but a site on an external server

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a CMS, you should look into static site generators. I use Jekyll for all my PhoneGap apps, including one that has a non-technical user updating the content.

Content pages are set up as markdown files with a yaml header - not quite as user friendly as a full CMS, but still pretty easy to edit.

I have jekyll set up as a build step, so all the generated html files get packaged and deployed to the device as part of a single click build process.

You could export static html from a web based CMS, but that will likely be more trouble than it is worth by the time you debug all the bits that were designed to work online only.

Loading the pages directly from the web will work just fine technically, but runs into several of the app store rules - no significant added functionality, no offline access and possibly downloading executable code.

Answer (score 0):

With [DrupalGap](http://drupalgap.org), it is possible to create iOS (and Android, etc) mobile applications using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) and a [Drupal](http://drupal.org) powered website.

**What is Drupal?**

> Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions
>   of websites and applications. It’s built, used, and supported by an
>   active and diverse community of people around the world.

**Why Drupal?**

> Use Drupal to build everything from personal blogs to enterprise
>   applications. Thousands of add-on modules and designs let you build
>   any site you can imagine.

**What is DrupalGap?**

> DrupalGap is an open source mobile application development kit for
>   Drupal websites. It uses Drupal, PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile and jDrupal.
>
> With the DrupalGap Mobile Application Development Kit and API,
>   developers can create custom multi-platform mobile applications that
>   communicate with their Drupal websites.

**Helpful Links**

- [DrupalGap Getting Started Guide](http://drupalgap.org/get-started)
- [DrupalGap SDK on GitHub](https://github.com/signalpoint/DrupalGap)